# Strange behaviour of suggestion bar to solve an ODE, potential bug

Tags: differential-equations, predictive-interface

Input`E^(-(1/2) x[t]^2) (Derivative[1][x][t]^2 - (x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]) == 0`and evaluate, then press the solve ode button on the suggestion bar. It will return

```
DSolve[E^(-(1/2) x[ t]^2) (Derivative[1][x][t]^2 - (x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]) == 
0, {x[t], x[t]}, {t}]
```

Normally, the suggestion bar returns `{x[t]}` instead of `{x[t], x[t]}`.

Although the results are seemingly the same, I don't know the difference between them, if it exists, because I found no such usage of `{x[t], x[t]}` in the documentation. Is it a bug or an expected behaviour?

Produced on OS X 10.10.3, Mathematica 10.1

Comment: The argument is supposed to be a list of functions/independent variables of the ODE.  Apparently it does not matter if a variable is repeated.  I agree with you that it would be better if the suggestions bar gave a single instance.  There is a suggestions-bar feedback button on the suggestions you can use to send an email to Wolfram Support.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I will report in this case.